# bootstrap progress bar not showing when code is run

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i have the following and i expected the progress to show on  the background, but nothing shows

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="progress progress-striped">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-    valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not viewing this in Internet Explorer, are you? Because it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the bootstrap css files first

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Make the following changes to your code:
`<DOCTYPE HTML>` to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and `aria-    valuenow="40"` to `aria-valuenow="40"`

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leejinhuey/v6zP5/)

If you can't see the progress bar in the fiddle, then you're probably using an incompatible browser.

> Progress bars use CSS3 transitions and animations to achieve some of their effects.    >These features are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below or older versions of >Firefox. Opera 12 does not support animations.

Comment: i just did, i added <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: and nothing changed, its still blank

Comment: but this will print the 45% complete, it wont show the bar, right?

Comment: Instead of `aria-    valuenow="40"`, make it `aria-valuenow="40"`.

Comment: yh it is aria-valuenow="40", i dont know why this isnt working

Comment: Oh, I just noticed. It's `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

Comment: THAT DIDNT STILL WORK :(

Comment: actually i have a project am running, but this code didnt work, so i decided to run it on a separate to check what was going on

Comment: See my comment on your post

Comment: Can you see the fiddle?

Comment: fiddle? i think i know whats happening, on the console it gives me this error

Comment: GET file://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: That doesn't look like an error. What console is this? Nonetheless, it seems to suggest that your server cannot grab the bootstrap css files for some reason, so I recommend downloading the files to your server and accessing them locally.

Comment: i just downloaded the file and still nothing

Comment: Version 32.0.1700.72 m, am running this version

Comment: Please, be a little more verbose. You changed the link in the HTML to your local file? Are you still seeing the error message? Version of what?

Comment: hey no worries, i works now, i did download bootstrap and put in folder, but i didnt give it the right reference in my link tag, it works now, thanks alot for helping, i really appreciate

Comment: @user3137376 Did this answer your question in the end?